# Saber qual botão foi clicado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Amigos,
Tenho 4 botões tipo `<input tupe="button">`, cada um tem uma classe diferente pois são formatados de formas diferentes. Ambos botões tem a mesma ação, com valores diferentes apenas. gostaria de saber como pegar esses valores desses botões em uma função jquery, pois o id é único, a classe é diferente.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Com jQuery podes fazer simplesmente:

```
$('button[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
   // e aqui, o this é o botão clicado
   var id = this.id;
   var classes = this.classList;
});
```

Se quiseres fazer só com JavaScript nativo podes fazer assim:

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll('button[type="button"]');
for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++){
  botoes[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       // e aqui, o this é o botão clicado
       var id = this.id;
       var classes = this.classList;
  });
}
```

Nota:

- repara que tens `tupe` em vez de `type`.
- lembra-te que as IDs devem ser unicas, e as classes partilhadas. No teu texto dizes "cada um tem uma classe diferente [...] o id é único", se calhar está certo mas a descrição dá-me ideia que não